# laravel project, page that has many notes note insertion issue

Tags: php, html, laravel

hello I am working on laravel project that am using relations between 2 tables i add a page that has many notes, so i am making a web page that allows me to add many pages and it shows the title of each page and inside every page, i can add many notes, I have problem in adding notes, am not sure if it is a problem in the route file or the blade file

i tried to add many variables in add note section in blade file but most of them gave me the msg of undefined even if am using the same variable i already have defined in the function inside the controller

**showonepage.blade.php**

```php
<div class="row list-group-item-info page-title">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     {{$id_show_single->title}}
    </div>
</div>

@foreach($id_show_single->notes as $note )
<div class="row list-group-item">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
     {{$note->text}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Edit</button> 
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach

<div class="row list-group-item">
    <form method="POST" action="showdatapage/{{$id_page->id}}/notestore">
      {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="note_text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Note . . .">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>
          </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```php
Route::get('showdatapage/{id_show_single}','PageController@ViewSinglePage');
Route::post('showdatapage/{id_page}/addnote','NoteController@PostGeneralNote');
```

```php
class NoteController extends Controller
{
    public function PostGeneralNote(Request $NoteReq, Page $id_page) {

        $note = new note;
        $note->text = $NoteReq->note_text;
        $id_page->pages()->save($note);
        return back();
    }
}
```

**Pagecontroller**

```php
public function ViewSinglePage(page $id_show_single) { 
   return view('showdatapdgone',compact('id_show_single')); 
}
```

the final result when i type the id of page it gives me the page title and the note belongs to it but when i try to add new not it gave me not found page and i noticed in url for ex: http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdatapage/1 after adding new not it becomes http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdatapage/showdatapage/1 it doubled the url address

Comment: Please, try to be more clear in explaining your problem.

Comment: Change your action to have a `/` at the beginning of the URL, or else it will be relative to your current URL.

Answer (score 0):

my project has 2 tables one for pages and one for notes , each page has title i connect each title in database with auto increment id the same id that i use to show single page, single page with single title from table "pages" can contain many notes, in notes table i have text column which is connect to auto increment id and there is a foreign key page_id i use to in making relation between 2 tables, the project is working good, except the add of notes in single page which has single title n single page id